# How do I generate barplots showing gene expression data?

Tags: python, r

I don't know exactly what is the name for these plots. I'm interested in plotting these plots.Can some one refer me a good packages, show reproducible helpful code that I'd be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: these are just normal barplots, and this site is not a code-writing service

Comment: Hi Park. You've kind of got this round the wrong way. _You_ provide the reproducible code - we fix what doesn't work. It sounds like you want someone to write you a tutorial. There are lots of places online where you will get a better introductory tutorial about producing bar plots in R than anything folks here will produce in an answer. Try "bar plot ggplot2 tutorial" in a Google search.

Comment: Please see [help/on-topic], [ask].

Answer (score 2):

This could be a start.

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(groups = c(rep("A",4), rep("B",4)), 
    wt = c(rnorm(4), rnorm(4)) , 
    var= c(rep(1,2),rep(2,2),rep(1,2),rep(2,2)))

ggplot(df) + 
  geom_bar(aes(var, wt, fill = as.factor(groups)), 
           position = "dodge", stat = "summary", fun = "mean")
```

Comment: Can you show me the how the dateset looks, thanks.

Comment: df is the dataset